# Why does this Ownership transfer does not cause an error?

Tags: rust, scope, ownership

I'm working through the ownership section.
I wrote the following code an expected an error.

Question: Why isn't there an error in the first compiling version?

This one compiles:

> fn main () {
>
> ```
> let mut x = String::from("vier");
> let mut y = x.to_owned()+"1"; //here x should go out of scope, because used in a method
> let mut z = x.to_owned()+"2";
>
> x.push_str("test");
>
>
> println!("{}", x);
> println!("{}", y);
> println!("{}", z);
>  }
> ```

This one does not compile:

> fn main () {
>
> ```
> let mut x = String::from("vier");
> let mut y = x;//x out of scope
> let mut z = x;//x out of scope
>
> x.push_str("test");
>
>
> println!("{}", x);
> println!("{}", y);
> println!("{}", z);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`to_owned()` only takes a reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned), not ownership. You'll notice that  the blanket implementation for `T` requires `T: Clone`:

```rust
impl<T> ToOwned for T where
    T: Clone, 
type Owned = T
```

That indicates that `.to_owned()` uses `.clone()` for any type that implements `Clone`.

Answer (score 2):

[`to_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) is a method from `borrow::ToOwned` trait. Which returns an owned version (cloned/copy) of the element. It just takes an `&self` so the object is not really moved.

Comment: It's from `ToOwned`, not `Borrow`.